# Sending Array List Between Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently I am sending one Array List from form2 to form 1 and it works fine.

```
Form1 form2 = new Form1(this, SampleArrayList); //pass form reference and an arraylist
form2.Show();
this.Hide();
```

And on form1 I associate SampleArrayList with local Array List.

```
Form2 formParent;
ArrayList SampleArrayList;
public MainForm(Form2 par, ArrayList _SampleArrayList)
{            
       InitializeComponent();
       this.formParent = par;
       this.SampleArrayList = _SampleArrayList;
}
```

However I want to avoid creating new instance of Form1

```
form2 = new Form1(this, SampleArrayList);
```

I want to send Array List to currently running instance of Form1. What would be best way to do this. Thank you

Comment: Since you are holding a reference to `SampleArrayList',  why do you need to pass it back to Form1?

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` instead of `List<T>`?

Comment: At some point you need to create a new instance of the old form, so when should you make one and when should you use an existing one?

Comment: Backward compatibility lot of stuff was created in ArrayList so I don't want to change that since its working.
Also form1 needs to be constantly updated and if I create new instance I lose the old data.

Comment: That was meant to be a leading question.  Are you creating a new form when you click button A and re-using an existing one when you click button B?  Should you create a new one if one doesn't exist and re-use it if one already does exist?  Both of those statements map fairly well into code.  Most likely you'll need to hold onto the second form as a field, not just a local variable in a method, if you aren't already.

Comment: Form1 is created first, clicking add button creates Form2. Clicking submit button hides Form2 and creates new instance of Form1 along with old instance which I didn't want to dispose of.

I want to click submit button on Form2 and go back to running instance of Form1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote of OP in the comments above:

> Form1 is created first, clicking add button creates Form2. Clicking
>   submit button hides Form2 and creates new instance of Form1 along with
>   old instance which I didn't want to dispose of. I want to click submit
>   button and go back to running instance of Form1.

That's really a larger problem then.  Here's a nice solution that I like.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string dataFromThisForm; //can be whatever
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 otherForm = new Form2();
        //pass some data to other form
        otherForm.SomeData = dataFromThisForm; 

        this.Hide();
        otherForm.Show();

        //when the other form is closed
        otherForm.FormClosed += (sender2, e2) =>
        {
            this.Show();

            string newData = otherForm.NewData;
        };

        //when the other form is hidden.
        otherForm.VisibleChanged += (sender2, e2) =>
        {
            this.Show();

            string newData = otherForm.NewData;
        };
    }
}
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Use SomeData to populate controls.
    }

    public string SomeData { get; set; } //data passed in from other form

    public string NewData { get; private set; }  //data to expose to other form

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewData = "SomeDataToPassToForm1";
        //this.Close();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

A few notes:

- You're passing around an `ArrayList`, rather than strings as I did in
  this example.  An `ArrayList` is a mutable reference type, whereas
  `string` is immutable.  This means that you can just modify the
  `ArrayList` passed to Form2, and those changes will be reflected in
  the variable in Form1 since they both point to the same underlying
  `ArrayList`.  I left this code in here as it covers the general case
  though.
- You say that you hide Form2 when you click the submit button. 
  Normally in this design you would close it since it won't be needed
  anymore.  If you really don't plan to use it again I suggest closing
  it.  If you really do plan to show that form again then just hiding
  it is fine.
- If you close Form2 on submit it will fire the FormClosing event, if
  you just hide it it will fire the Visible event.  You should probably
  remove one of those two event handlers in my code depending on
  whether you actually close it or hide it. If you sometimes do one and
  sometimes the other then feel free to leave both.  You won't actually
  harm anything (other than confusing people) if you leave both in even
  if you only use one.

Comment: No problem.  This is a very common issue to come up in winforms, and as a result there are a lot of different solutions.  Some are okay, but quite a lot of them are really rather poor from a design perspective.  (I.e. the suggestions in this thread to just start making stuff static, rather than scoping everything appropriately.)

Answer (score 1):

A static class that would act as a communications platform within your application could solve the problem or both forms could be owned by the same object.

Comment: If you create a static class, and make the array a public static property, than you can get to that array from any class/form in your program. Of course, then your form2 wouldn't need an array in it's constructor anymore, because it can get it from the static class.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a method to Form1 that accepts the Array list.

Something like:

```
public void Setup(ArrayList SampleArrayList)
{
    // Do what you need here...
}
```

Then you could call this method from inside your constructor (to keep the constructor the same), and call Setup when you need to change the list the Form is using.

Your code above would be like this:

```
// If you needed a new instance of Form1, it wouldn't change
Form1 form2 = new Form1(this, SampleArrayList); //pass form reference and an arraylist
form2.Show();
this.Hide();

// If you already had an instance in the form2 variable
form2.Setup(SampleArrayList);
```

No matter what, if you are using .NET 2.0 or greater, I would recommend using a generic List to store list data instead of ArrayList.

Comment: Doesn't work it still creates new instance each time

Comment: When you creating the new instance is up to you - if you keep a reference to the form after you create it, you can use the `Setup` method I recommended to give it a new ArrayList.  (maybe you need to make the `form2` variable a private field in `Form1`, so you can track whether you have created the form yet.)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a static property in the `Form1` class if you don't need to create a instance of it. For example:

```
private static ArrayList _SampleArrayList;
public static ArrayList SampleArrayList
{
    get { return _SampleArrayList; }
    set { _SampleArrayList = value; }
}
```

and when you want update the `ArrayList` write simply:

```
 Form1.SampleArrayList = SampleArrayList;
```

**PS:** I reccomend you use a `List<>` instead of an `ArrayList`.

If you don't know the type instead of `ArrayList` use `List<object>` else `List<T>`.

**EDIT:**

If **form1** and **form2** are both an istance of the same class you only have to make the `ArrayList` static.

Comment: but how would this work if the sampleArrayList is already declared in form2

 public  ArrayList sampleArrayList = new ArrayList();

Comment: If it's already created pass the ArrayList. So after creation of it write `Form1.SampleArrayList = sampleArrayList;`.

Comment: but I can't pass the array without creating new form. Is there any way just to pass it to existing form.

Comment: No using my code you can do it without creating a new form. When you do `Form1.SampleArrayList = sampleArrayList;` you are just passing the arraylist to all the existing object of type `Form1`. Try it and tell me the results.